# Compare facts and output result

Tags: prolog

I am new to Prolog and I am attempting to make a quiz where the user is given 3 questions and 3 options for each question. After each question is asked, the 3 possible choice of answers are shown. The user types an answer for that question and the next question is shown and the quiz continues until all 3 are asked and answer.

What I want to do next is compare each user answer with the correct answer for that question and output, if the user is right,wrong or skipped a question. I think I'm correct in saying that I need to compare with facts in the database knowledge with static facts. I realise this it not a real problem, but if someone could give me advice as how best to achieve my goal, it would be greatly appreciated. I'm just confused. More info will be provided if need be.

```
question(1,'What is the fifth planet of our Solar System?').
question(2,'In what year was George Best born?').
question(3,'What is the capital of Austraila?').

possibleAns(1,[mars,jupiter,saturn]).
possibleAns(2,[1945,1946,1948]).
possibleAns(3,[sydney,canberra,melbourne]).

rightAns(1,jupiter).
rightAns(2,1946).
rightAns(3,canberra).

skip(s).

%Confused as to how best to achieve the comparing and output
check_answer(AnsNo,userChoice):-
    rightAns(AnsNo,Choice),
    userAnswer(AnsNo,userChoice)    

getChoice(ChoiceNo,ChoiceList):-
    write('Choose from'),nl,
    write(ChoiceList),nl,
    read(Choice),
    (member(Choice,ChoiceList);skip(Choice)),
    %userAnswer will compare with rightAnswer
    assert(userAnswer(ChoiceNo,Choice)).
getChoice(ChoiceNo,ChoiceList):-
    writeln('Illegal Choice'),
    getChoice(ChoiceNo,ChoiceList).

//check if the question has been asked
//if not, write question
//get users choice and move to next question
get_question(PreviousAsked):-
    question(QNum,Text),
    \+ member(QNum,PreviousAsked),
    write(Text),nl,
    possibleAns(QNum,ChoiceList),
    getChoice(QNum,ChoiceList),
    get_question([QNum|PreviousAsked]).

get_question(_).

start_quiz:-
    get_question([]).
```

---

```
Updated
getChoice(ChoiceNo,ChoiceList):-
    write('Choose from'),nl,
    write(ChoiceList),nl,
    read(Choice),
    (member(Choice,ChoiceList);skip(Choice)),
    assert(userAnswer(ChoiceNo,Choice)).
    (   rightAns(ChoiceNo,Choice)
    ->   write('Right!'),nl;
    write('Wrong,'),nl).
```

Answer (score 2):

When possible, we should avoid *assert* and *retract*, and usually we are rewarded by simpler programs, easier to understand and debug.

In your case, you could collect initially the list of questions Qs

```
findall(Q, question(Q,_), Qs)
```

and then run a loop until Qs is empty. Remove a question *only* when the user selected it *and* answered in appropriate way.

*edit* I keept only question/2,possibleAns/2,rightAns/2, and with this code

```
show(Q) :-
    question(Q, T),
    possibleAns(Q, As),
    format('~d: ~s ~w~n', [Q, T, As]).

loop([]).
loop(Qs) :-
    maplist(show, Qs),
    (   (read((Q,Y)),
         select(Q, Qs, Rs),
         rightAns(Q, Y)
        ) -> loop(Rs) ; loop(Qs)
    ).

quiz :-
    findall(Q, question(Q,_), Qs),
    loop(Qs).
```

I get

```
?- quiz.
1: What is the fifth planet of our Solar System? [mars,jupiter,saturn]
2: In what year was George Best born? [1945,1946,1948]
3: What is the capital of Austraila? [sydney,canberra,melbourne]
|: 1,mars.
1: What is the fifth planet of our Solar System? [mars,jupiter,saturn]
2: In what year was George Best born? [1945,1946,1948]
3: What is the capital of Austraila? [sydney,canberra,melbourne]
|: 1,jupiter.
2: In what year was George Best born? [1945,1946,1948]
3: What is the capital of Austraila? [sydney,canberra,melbourne]
|: 2,1946.
3: What is the capital of Austraila? [sydney,canberra,melbourne]
|: 3,canberra.
true .
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you have defined `rightAns/2` in your database, I would suggest that you compare the results within `getChoice` like this:

```
getChoice(ChoiceNo,ChoiceList):-
    write('Choose from'),nl,
    write(ChoiceList),nl,
    read(Choice),
    (member(Choice,ChoiceList);skip(Choice)),
    (   rightAns(ChoiceNo,Choice)
    ->  write('Right!'),nl
    ;   write('Wrong.'),nl).
```

If you don't like the idea of comparing the answers inside of `getChoice/2` (because you want to preserve the meaning of your predicate as pure as possible) you may create a simple rule to do so:

```
check_answer(AnsNo,userChoice)
    (   rightAns(AnsNo,userChoice)
    ->  write('Right!'),nl
    ;   write('Wrong.'),nl).
```

I would also recommend that you use the cut (`!`) or any other mechanism to prevent backtracking when the quiz has finished.

Comment: Thanks for the assistance Carles. That has helped me. After all questions have been answered, you check users answers, how would you go through each user answer and output if that is right or wrong. For example, Q1 right, Q2 wrong, Q3 right.

Comment: You could use `assert(correct(ChoiceNo)).` right after `write('Right!').`. Then, calling `findall(Q,correct(Q),Qs).` at the end of the quiz would give you all correctly answered questions. However, this is the _quick-and-dirty_ way. If you prefer avoiding `assert` calls (as @CapelliC recommended) I would suggest you think of a different approach for your algorithm; more similar to that of @CapelliC.